# Cloning table row with Glyphicon and Bootstrap "Data Live Search" (Dropdown)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Rows created successfully while clicking the glyphicon (+) but bootstrap dropdown (data live search) is not working in the 2nd row and other rows (after cloning).

Here is the attached runnable code. Please let me know the solution.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".glyphicon-plus").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").clone(true).appendTo("#ruleTable");

  });
  $(".glyphicon-remove").click(function() {
    if ($('#ruleTable tr').length > 2) {
      $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    liveSearch: true,
    showSubtext: true
  });
});
```

```css
.bootstrap-select .dropdown-menu>li>a small.muted {
  display: none;
}

.bootstrap-select .dropdown-toggle .filter-option {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 38px;
}

.bootstrap-select .dropdown-toggle .filter-option:before {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select-picker@0.3.1/js/picker.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="ruleTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">

      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
        Name
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="color:lawngreen"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="color:red"></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
          <option>--Select--</option>
          <option>Mustard</option>
          <option>Ketchup</option>
          <option>Relish</option>
        </select>
      </td>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Here is the runnable code in JSFiddle.  https://jsfiddle.net/karthisena/mL4trwut/

Comment: SO is a terrible debugger! What have you tried to solve this? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

First problem that you have is that you are binding to the existing at that time `.glyphicon-plus` and `.glyphicon-remove` buttons. You would need to change the event bindings to:

```
$("#ruleTable").on('click', '.glyphicon-plus', function() {  });
```

Another problem is that you clone the initialized `selectpicker` which contains events, that change the existing select picker, instead of new one. You would need to recreate new `<select>` and initialize it again using `.selectpicker()` for the cloned row.

Here's an updated fiddle, where I've extracted your row into a separate template, that is used to create new rows: https://jsfiddle.net/x8s5evLo/